# Adding a right arrow to the right of D

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows, tikz-cd

Here is the code I found here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    & A\ar{rd}\\
    B\ar{ru} \ar{r} \ar{rd}[swap] & C\ar{r} & D\\
    & E\ar{ru}[swap]
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

but I want to add an arrow to the right of $D$ going to $F.$

Is there any advice of how to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add another object separated with a `&` and an arrow to the right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    & A\ar{rd}\\
    B\ar{ru} \ar{r}\ar{rd} & C\ar{r} & D\ar{r} & F\\
    & E\ar{ru}
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see that you neglected the [swap], is there a reason for this?

Comment: `swap` is an option for an arrow label. Without a label this option will raise an error. Your code, as it is, is not compilable because of that option

Comment: what if I want to draw a dashed arrow between A and F?

Comment: @mathmusic then add the option `dashed` but to the arrow, not to the name. The arrow from A should be `\ar[dashed]{r}`. If you want to bend this arrow you can add this option too: `\ar[dashed,bend left=20]{r}`, for example. In general options that modify the arrow goes before the direction of the arrow and options to modify the label goes before the label (in this case, one label should be added)